# Dependency Injection: Is it possible for a class to push itself into the Unity container in the constructor?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm using WPF + MVVM + Unity.

Sometimes, it's impossible to avoid letting controls create their own classes, particularly if a user adds lines are to a grid, or a TreeList is absolutely determined to create its own ViewModel.

Is it possible to get a class to add itself to the Unity container in its own constructor, so other classes can lazily pull them out of the container on demand?

Or, am I doing something wrong at an architectural level, and there is indeed a way to make Unity fit perfectly into WPF's universe?

Comment: Do not even think about using unity if you up to creating a custom control. Thats a crime :)))

Comment: What do you mean by a "control".  A view/code-behind or a viewmodel?  I would not recommend using Unity for a code-behind, but definitely for a viewmodel.  Also check out [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx).